# If we consider $f\neq 0$, can we infer that $\int_{-1}^1 f(t)dt=0$ iff $f$ is odd?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, continuity

I am considering continuous functions $f\in C[-1,1]$. We know tha the area under an even function over a symmetric interval can be calculated by doubling the area over the positive  x -axis. For an odd function, instead, the integral over a symmetric interval equals zero, because half the area is negative. So, for odd functions $f\in C[-1,1]$ we have that
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(t)dt=0$$
The question is the following. If we consider $f\neq 0$, can we infer that $\int_{-1}^1 f(t)dt=0$ iff $f$ is odd?

Comment: Surely not. You can easily construct (continuous, not identially zero, not odd) functions with $\int_{-1}^0 f(t)dt = -1$ and $\int_{0}^1 f(t)dt = 1$.

Comment: However, if $\int_{-x}^x f(t)\,\mathrm d t=0$ for all $x$, then indeed $f$ is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we cannot infer that. For instance,$$\int_{-1}^13x^2-1\,\mathrm dx=0,$$but $3x^2-1$ is an even function.

Comment: The question was about the odd function. I'm fairly sure that the statement in the question is in fact true, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @bb_823 The question was “If we consider $f\neq 0$, can we infer that $\int_{-1}^1 f(t)dt=0$ iff $f$ is odd?” I don't see what is it that you mean when you say that the question is about the odd function. Which odd function?

Answer (score 1):

No just take for example $f(x) = 1$ for $|x|\leq 1/2$ and $f(x) = -1$ for $|x|>1/2$

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. An example may be a continuous function $f$ which is $x$ if $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $\frac{3}{2}x^2$ if $-1\leq x\leq 0$.

Indeed

$$\int_{-1}^1 f(t)dt=\int_{-1}^0 f(t)dt+\int_{0}^1 f(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{2}=0$$